# Multiple D3 TreeMap on the same page with different div id's

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, treemap

I am trying to make multiple D3 based treemap but the tree map is generating only at the place for last div element (say I am plotting for #chart1 , #chart2 and #chart3 but only one treemap is generating that too at position of #chart3) but with the data of first chart only. I am pasting the two piece of codes for different div id's

**chart1**

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

            var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: -40},
                width = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var color = d3.scale.category10();

            var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
                .size([width, height])
                .sticky(true)
                .value(function(d) { return d.credit; });

            var div = d3.select("#chart1").append("div")
                .style("position1", "relative")
                .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
                .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
                .style("left", margin.left + "px")
                .style("top", margin.top + "px");



            d3.json("sem1.json", function(error, root1) {
              if (error) throw error;

              var node = div.datum(root1).selectAll(".node")
                  .data(treemap.nodes)
                  .enter().append("div")
                  .attr("class", "node")
                  .call(position1)
                  .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.name) : null; })
                  .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; });


              d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
               var value = this.value === "count"
                    ? function() { return 1; }
                    : function(d) { return d.size; };
                node
                    .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
                  .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .call(position1);
              });



            });

            function position1() {
              this.style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })
                  .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + "px"; })
                  .style("width", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px"; })
                  .style("height", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px"; });
            }

            </script>
```

and **chart2**

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

            var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: -40},
                width = 220 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var color = d3.scale.category10();

            var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
                .size([width, height])
                .sticky(true)
                .value(function(d) { return d.credit; });

            var div = d3.select("#chart2").append("div")
                .style("position2", "relative")
                .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
                .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
                .style("left", margin.left + "px")
                .style("top", margin.top + "px");



            d3.json("sem2.json", function(error, root2) {
              if (error) throw error;

              var node = div.datum(root2).selectAll(".node")
                  .data(treemap.nodes)
                  .enter().append("div")
                  .attr("class", "node")
                  .call(position2)
                  .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.name) : null; })
                  .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; });


              d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
               var value = this.value === "count"
                    ? function() { return 1; }
                    : function(d) { return d.size; };
                node
                    .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
                  .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .call(position2);
              });



            });

            function position2() {
              this.style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })
                  .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + "px"; })
                  .style("width", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px"; })
                  .style("height", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px"; });
            }

            </script>
```

There is some problem with the positioning of the element, and tried changing with two different position function to position1 and position2.

Comment: You have variable scoping issues.  You are re-declaring `var div` three times at the same scope, it'll only ever represent the div with id of chart3.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it solved my problem. Infact there was same error in treemap too, which I got to know after this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct one, after above reccomendation:

**chart1**

```
            <script type="text/javascript">

            var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: -40},
                width = 220 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var color = d3.scale.category10();

            var treemap1 = d3.layout.treemap()
                .size([width, height])
                .sticky(true)
                .value(function(d) { return d.credit; });

            var div1 = d3.select("#chart6").append("div")
                .style("position1", "relative")
                .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
                .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
                .style("left", margin.left + "px")
                .style("top", margin.top + "px");



            d3.json("sem1.json", function(error, root1) {
              if (error) throw error;

              var node = div1.datum(root1).selectAll(".node")
                  .data(treemap1.nodes)
                  .enter().append("div")
                  .attr("class", "node")
                  .call(position1)
                  .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.name) : null; })
                  .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; });


              d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
               var value = this.value === "count"
                    ? function() { return 1; }
                    : function(d) { return d.size; };
                node
                    .data(treemap1.value(value).nodes)
                  .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .call(position1);
              });



            });

            function position1() {
              this.style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })
                  .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + "px"; })
                  .style("width", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px"; })
                  .style("height", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px"; });
            }

            </script>
```

**chart2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: -40},
                width = 220 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var color = d3.scale.category10();

            var treemap2 = d3.layout.treemap()
                .size([width, height])
                .sticky(true)
                .value(function(d) { return d.credit; });

            var div2 = d3.select("#chart7").append("div")
                .style("position2", "relative")
                .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
                .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
                .style("left", margin.left + "px")
                .style("top", margin.top + "px");



            d3.json("sem2.json", function(error, root2) {
              if (error) throw error;

              var node = div2.datum(root2).selectAll(".node")
                  .data(treemap2.nodes)
                  .enter().append("div")
                  .attr("class", "node")
                  .call(position2)
                  .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.name) : null; })
                  .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; });


              d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
               var value = this.value === "count"
                    ? function() { return 1; }
                    : function(d) { return d.size; };
                node
                    .data(treemap2.value(value).nodes)
                  .transition()
                    .duration(1500)
                    .call(position2);
              });



            });

            function position2() {
              this.style("left", function(d) { return d.x + "px"; })
                  .style("top", function(d) { return d.y + "px"; })
                  .style("width", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dx - 1) + "px"; })
                  .style("height", function(d) { return Math.max(0, d.dy - 1) + "px"; });
            }

            </script>
```